# I can't scrape all products on Amazon

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

I want to get links of products in a store. The code I wrote below sometimes doesn't get all the products. There are 24 products on a page, but it gives 14 links. What is the reason of this ? How can I use webdriverwait better.

```
def nextPageButton(self):
    nextPageButton = WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class = 's-pagination-item s-pagination-next s-pagination-button s-pagination-separator']")))
    nextPageButton.click()

def getAllProducts(self):
    products = []
    while True:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class = 'a-link-normal s-no-outline']")))
        productsA = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class = 'a-link-normal s-no-outline']")
        print(len(productsA))
        for a in productsA:
            products.append(a.get_attribute("href")) 
        try:
            self.nextPageButton()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
    return products
```

Product
[image: Product]

Next button
[image: Next button]

Comment: Hello. Provide the relevant HTML code wherein these anchor tags are container, otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly you have to scroll down a bit to collect all the desired elements.

Comment: I tried the CTRL+END combination but it didn't work because it was too fast. I put a 4 second cooldown and the problem went away. I don't know how to set wait time more dynamically.